# Python: using a regular expression to match one line of HTML

Tags: python, html, regex

This simple Python method I put together just checks to see if Tomcat is running on one of our servers.

```
import urllib2
import re
import sys

def tomcat_check():

    tomcat_status = urllib2.urlopen('http://10.1.1.20:7880')
    results = tomcat_status.read()
    pattern = re.compile('<body>Tomcat is running...</body>',re.M|re.DOTALL)
    q = pattern.search(results)
    if q == []:
        notify_us()
    else:
         print ("Tomcat appears to be running")
    sys.exit()
```

If this line is not found :

```
<body>Tomcat is running...</body>
```

It calls :

```
notify_us()
```

Which uses SMTP to send an email message to myself and another admin that Tomcat is no longer runnning on the server...

I have not used the re module in Python before...so I am assuming there is a better way to do this... I am also open to a more graceful solution with Beautiful Soup ... but haven't used that either..

Just trying to keep this as simple as possible...

Comment: For an in-house script as simple as this, why do you need a "better" solution? What is your definition of "better"? Does this not work for you?

Comment: The simpler an in-house script becomes, the more likely future people looking at it will be able to figure out what it does when they look at it later.  Trying to keep things simple while writing a new script is a good idea.  As for the justification for spending the time actually discussing it, once you realize, "I just wrote some code that is probably not as good as it should be," the motivation is as much about learning as it is about maintenance.

Comment: @Bryan By better , I mean I am not sure if I am using regex efficiently ... I assume I am not

Comment: @skylarking: sometimes efficiency isn't important. Especially considering the fact that you're pinging a website which is a relatively slow operation. Speeding up this script will have zero impact other than to take more time to develop.

Comment: @Brian: I agree. I was speaking about this specific script. In general, even small in-house scripts need to be of appropriate quality.

Comment: @Bryan: I was also speaking about this specific script.  The justification for him worrying about it when writing about it was general, but the justification for him spending even more time on it now was realizing he had just written substandard code and wanting to improve his coding abilities by learning how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use regex here at all? Why not just a simple string search?:

```
if not '<body>Tomcat is running...</body>' in results:
   notify_us()
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is what I was looking for. To answer your question...I think I have a tendency to get 'lost in the weeds' and overcomplicate simple problems sometimes when using unfamiliar modules... In this case 're'.

Answer (score 2):

```
if not 'Tomcat is running' in results:
    notify_us()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different methods:

### [str.find()](http://codepad.org/F2LU1piS)

```
if results.find("Tomcat is running...") != -1:
    print "Tomcat appears to be running"
else:
    notify_us()
```

### [Using X in Y](http://codepad.org/PuOrXuGY)

```
if "Tomcat is running..." in result:
    print "Tomcat appears to be running"
else:
    notify_us()
```

### [Using Regular Expressions](http://codepad.org/UPPgFjnR)

```
if re.search(r"Tomcat is running\.\.\.", result):
    print "Tomcat appears to be running"
else:
    notify_us()
```

Personally, I prefer the membership operator to test if the string is in another string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be looking for a fixed string (not a regexp) that you have some control over and can be expected to be consistent, [str.find()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) should do just fine. Or what Daniel said.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, regular expressions aren't suited for parsing XML like structures (at least, for more complex queries). I would do something like that:

```
from lxml import etree
import urllib2

def tomcat_check(host='127.0.0.1', port=7880):
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://%s:%d' % (host, port))
    html = etree.HTML(response.read())
    return html.findtext('.//body') == 'Tomcat is running...'

if tomcat_check('10.1.1.20'):
    print 'Tomcat is running...'
else:
    # notify someone
```

Comment: in this case, he's not so much parsing as he is looking for a specific sequence of bytes.